# Cannot load genefilter package from library

Tags: r

So I try to load by `library(genefilter)`

But I keep getting the error:

`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘genefilter’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...): unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Jerry Yu/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll': LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.`

I have already tried removing and reinstalling genefilter, but nothing has worked.

Comment: What haapens if you load Rcpp?

Comment: I get a pop up error saying entry point not found.